# bash script linux - process output of ifconfig -a output

Tags: linux, bash

I need to process the output of `ifconfig -a` 
I want to print only the IP address of the device if a single device name is given as a parameter to the script. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below command to get only the IP address of the device (You need to filter only the IP address part using `grep` command)

```
 /sbin/ifconfig -a | grep -i 'inet addr:'
```

Use `grep` command to filter the IP address as

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep -i 'inet addr:'
```

Yes, you can put the command in a script and run it. An example below

```
#!/bin/sh
# Shows ip address of eth3
/sbin/ifconfig -a | awk '/^eth3/,/^$/' | awk '/inet addr/ { print $2 }' | cut -d: -f2
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, so what happened when I have several devices in my computer? I have to write a script file processing the output of the `ifconfig -a`. So if in my computer there are `eth0`,`eth1`,`eth2`,`eth3`, `lo`. Then when I run the script file and give `eth3` as the parameter, the output should only print out the IP of `eth3` only

Comment: @user3626377, Yes and as I said you can as well filter `eth3` suing grep command. Consider reading MAN page of grep command and I am sure you will understand, how to go further.

Comment: Thanks, it would be easy if I can specified like that, but the task is that I am only allow to use `ifconfig -a` to get the IP

Comment: I tried that code you gave me but it doesnt give me any output. Is there a way to put the command into the bash script and you run it in command prompt. Like if my script name is `getIP.sh`, then I can run `./getIP.sh eth3` to get the IP

Comment: @user3626377, check edited answer again. Rest you need to figure out about how you will accept the interface as script parameter. It will be a good learning for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can read this

https://superuser.com/questions/644036/how-to-do-replace-using-sed-only-in-one-section-of-file

And use sed to get ip after your interface name.

For me work ok this line

```
ifconfig -a |sed '/^eth0/,/BROADCAST/ s/^.*inet addr:/NEED THIS ONE:/' \
 |grep 'NEED THIS ONE'|cut -f 2 -d: |cut -f 1 -d\
```

(note that at end of line after slash you need have space )

That can be read as " get line after eth0 and before BROADCAST, replace inet addr with NEED THIS ONE, get only that line with NEED THIS ONE and cut needed column"